# Why is this not throwing an error while testing in mocha using chai?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai

```
      foos.forEach(function(foo){
        expect(foo).to.have.ownProperty('stuff');
        expect(foo.stuff).to.exist;
        expect(foo.stuff.url).to.exist;
        expect(foo).to.have.deep.property('stuff.url').to.contain('http://');
      });

      done();
```

I'm looping over a list of items `foos` and if one of these tests fails, it doesn't stop execution, it just hangs. For example in my the 2nd and 3rd tests were failing but I got no indication of it. Can we not use `expect` inside for loops? It seems to work fine when data is valid.

Comment: [works for me](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/ae7129ce5d66d00886b8) (fwiw, it also works with the same `forEach` loop that you're using, I just split them into separate test cases for clarity)

Comment: Works for me too. ([see runnable](http://runnable.com/VSz-b-pRISA0PpVn/stackoverflow-chovy-question-for-node-js-and-hello-world)). Don't get the use of `done()` though. This test seems synchronous to me.

Comment: yeah. sorry. i had it wrapped in a promise, thus the `done()`. Just didn't include it. I discovered I needed a `.catch` to call done w/ error to see the erroneous tests.

Answer (score 0):

```
    doPromise()
        .then(function(foos){
              foos.forEach(function(foo){
                expect(foo).to.have.ownProperty('stuff');
                expect(foo.stuff).to.exist;
                expect(foo.stuff.url).to.exist;
                expect(foo).to.have.deep.property('stuff.url').to.contain('http://');
              });

              done();

        })
        .catch(function(err){
            done(err);
        })
```

Turns out I just need to handle the `.catch` and call `done(err)` to see the failing tests in the console.